# Is each range update in spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate() in Google Sheet API a Request call

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

This is my code below using the batchUpdate

```
SHEET.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ea_form_spreadsheet_id, body=bodys).execute()
```

In the "bodys" :

```
data = [
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AE3',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': ae3_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!E4',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': e4_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!Z4',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': z4_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AE3',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': ae3_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AE3',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': ae3_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AE3',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': ae3_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!Q9',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': q9_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!F11',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': f11_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!H12:H13',
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': h_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AI11:AI16',
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': ai_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AK21',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': ak21_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AK46:AK47',
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': ak_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!AJ57:AK58',
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': aj_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!C71',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': c71_values
    },
    {
        'range': staff_name + '!V67',
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': v67_values
    }
]

body = {
    'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': data
    }
```

So I will like to know if each of this range update is a request call or it is been summed up to just one Request Call.. in other words, what is the difference between **spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate** and **spreadsheets.values.update**

Answer (score 1):

As stated in each description of [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) and [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), one function sets values in one or more ranges of a spreadsheet and the other Sets values in a range of a spreadsheet respectively.

Based from the documentation - [Updating Spreadsheets : Batch update operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#batch_update_operations)

> The batchUpdate method works by taking one or more [Request](http://The%20batchUpdate%20method%20works%20by%20taking%20one%20or%20more%20Request%20objects,%20each%20one%20specifying%20a%20single%20kind%20of%20request%20to%20perform.%20There%20are%20many%20different%20kinds%20of%20requests.) objects, each one specifying a single kind of request to perform. There are many different kinds of requests.

A very good explanation of [batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch) is in Drive API:

> A batch request consists of multiple API calls combined into one HTTP request. Batching Requests reduce the number of HTTP connections your client has to make.

Hope this information helps.